# Uploading images to a server using an iPhone

Tags: iphone, streaming

How can I upload multiple files to a server using an iPhone, without error?

I am using HTTP for uploading images but some of images are missing.

Comment: Please post the relevant bits of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ASIHTTTRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library's ASIFormDataRequest method allows you to easily attach images to your post with a simple line of code for each imag, doing the whole thing asynchronously with simple success and failure delegate methods.

Just a suggestion. Posting your code is essential if you want to use your own code instead.